# Unable to retrieve struct from mapping

Tags: solidity, mapping, struct, library

I have a mapping like this:

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;
pragma experimental "v0.5.0";

...


mapping(bytes32 => LibMarket.Market) public hashToMarket;
```

where each `Market` is defined as:

```
struct Market {
    address a;
    uint256 b;
    uint256 c;
    string d;
    string e;
}
```

in a library file `LibMarket`.

In another contract, I'm trying to access this mapping using the hash like so:

```
    LibMarket.Market memory market = registry.hashToMarket(marketHash);
```

However, I'm receiving the error

> Exchange.sol:139:9: TypeError: Different number of components on the
>   left hand side (1) than on the right hand side (5).
>           LibMarket.Market memory market = registry.hashToMarket(marketHash);
>           ^----------------------------------------------------------------^

Why am I getting this error?

EDIT:

Although this doesn't answer this exact question. A simple workaround is to define a different getter function in the contract that has the `hashToMarket` mapping like so and it will work as intended:

```
function getMarket(bytes32 marketHash) public view returns(LibMarket.Market) {
    return hashToMarket[marketHash];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Since the error message is saying there are 5 results coming from the right-hand side of the assignment, that implies that the function `hashToMarket()` is not returning a `Market` object, but it's actually returning the five pieces of a `Market` object together (`a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, and `e`).

EDIT: That function is the default getter for a public mapping, which does indeed return the component pieces of the object rather than the assembled one. If you want to use that default getter, you can get the individual pieces, and then re-cast them into the known struct like:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;
contract MultiReturns {
    struct MyThing {
        uint256 a;
        uint256 b;
        uint256 c;
    }

    function getPieces() internal pure returns(uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) {
        return (123, 456, 789);
    }

    function doWork() public {
        (uint256 a, uint256 b, uint256 c) = getPieces();
        MyThing memory t = MyThing(a, b, c);
    }
}
```

Here the `getPieces` function is a sample function that returns multiple values (like the default getter in the original question was using). Note how the `doWork` method first gets the three pieces returned in one return statement from the `getPieces` function, and then uses them to construct the desired struct.

Comment: hashToMarket simply refers to the mapping I posted in the question. It is the automatically generated getter.

Comment: Ah, I see that now; updating my answer: